# Get all stored ID's from the array

Tags: php

```
**
```

I have an array which stores all ID's of episodes depending on tv show and amount of seasons. Each series has a different number of seasons.
And I need an Idea how to get all ID's from `$seasons[]['episodes']` no matter how many seasons it has.
I want it to returns to me all the ID of the episodes from the array.**

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                [name] => Season 1 
                [image_id] => 2119 
                [episodes] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 2122 
                    [1] => 2123 
                    [2] => 2124 
                    [3] => 2125 
                    [4] => 2126 
                ) 
                [year] => 2017 
                [description] => Atypical is a coming-of-age television series created by Robia Rashid for Netflix. It focuses on the life of 18-year-old Sam Gardner (Keir Gilchrist), who is on the autism spectrum. The first season was released on August 11, 2017, consisting of eight episodes. 
                [position] => 0 
            ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                [name] => Season 2 
                [image_id] => 2120 
                [episodes] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 2127 
                    [1] => 2128 
                    [2] => 2129 
                    [3] => 2130 
                    [4] => 2131 
                ) 
                [year] => 2018 
                [description] => The ten-episode second season was released on September 7, 2018. In October 2018, the series was renewed for a third season of ten episodes. 
                [position] => 0 
            ) 
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `array_column` function.

```
<?php
   $results = array_column($seasons, 'episodes'); // this will return 2d array of arrays with 'episodes'
   $final_results = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $results); // this will make 1d array of 2d array
   print_r($final_results);
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I extract IDs from array. Cuz my foreach loop returns "ArrayArray".

Comment: This is probably because you are getting array of arrays of episodes, you need to call `$final_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $previous_result_array);`, I edited my answer to be clear.